# How can I wrap one React component around another

Tags: reactjs, layout

I am new to React.  Basically, I have been given a HTML Bootstrap template. It is pretty simple... a left sidebar (always present), an adjacent menu (always present) and all other components fit adjacent to side bar and under menu.  I have attached a pic so you can easily see what I mean.

I can display the components but my dynamic components or the components that change are rendered below the sidebar and NOT next to it.  [image: Layout Pic]

I have tried to solve this issue for days... no luck. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Vincent

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post the relevant code for your components

Comment: Its hard to tell without seeing your code, but my assumption is that you may be self closing the element `<ParentComponent/>` that's supposed to contain the child element `<ChildElement/>` Instead you may need to do it like this `<ParentComponent><ChildElement/><ParentComponent/>` Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a css issue, make sure you have your child divs inside the parent and nothing is position absolute. if you have it online I can take a look.